# Camera with PhoneGap and Sencha touch

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to acccess the Camera using Sencha touch, ported to Android using Phonegap. As the Sencha touch [guide to using native APIs](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/native_apis) suggests, I declared the camera as a required: 
`Ext.require('Ext.device.Camera');`
But unfortunately, I get this error:

```
07-19 11:51:42.159: E/Web Console(8668): Uncaught Error: [Ext.Loader]
Failed loading './device/Camera.js', please verify that the file exists at 
file:///android_asset/www/lib/touch/sencha-touch-all-debug.js:8000
```

The sencha library does have Camera.js under device. I'm not sure why this error appears.

**Edit 1:** Still not able to find an answer. Would really appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

If you download the source code of sencha touch, there will be a directory named "device" in the "src" directory (after unzipping). Camera.js is in that directory. Seems sencha-touch-all-debug.js or sencha-touch-all.js not include the source code from all .js files in "device" directory. You must manually copy that directory to your android assets directory (eg the file:///android_asset/www/lib/touch/device).

or

You can copy the directory device in any place on your android assets (eg file:///android_asset/www/device). Then on the first of javascript declaration before you use sencha touch you must type the following code:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig ({
     paths: {
         'Ext.device': 'device'
     }
});
```

The code tells that "Ext.device" is reference to directory "device". Make sure the "device" directory is relative to the html file that calls the javascript (eg index.html). From the above code means the "device" directory is same location with the html file.

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately I cant verify this at the moment. I'll try it soon and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using phonegap for deploying, then use **Phonegap camera functionality**. I have used it in my app in following way:

1. Add `<script type="text/javascript"
   src="cordova-x.x.x.js"></script>` in your index.html    file.
2. Use following code to open Camera:

   ```
   navigator.camera.getPicture( cameraSuccess, cameraError, [ cameraOptions ] );
   ```

For more information on this api use following link:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera

Answer (score 0):

On the sencha forum there is a [thread](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?192354-Ext.device-problem) about it.

The problem appears to be the naming of Phongap - Cordova. Executing this before Sencha Touch is loaded should fix that.

```
if(typeof window.Cordova != 'undefined') {
    window.PhoneGap = window.Cordova;
}
```

Comment: Execute this before loading Sencha touch? How do i do that? My index.html has the sencha touch library files, so youre saying I create a js file and add it before the library files?

Comment: @Urban yes that's what I'm saying.. just between loading cordova and Sencha Touch

Comment: Well I had tried pretty much everything I could, and also what you just suggested. But I always got the same errors. Ultimately I gave up  on this due to time constraints. Hopefully someone is able to find a solution.